# Remove a RPM file without touching any of the files

Tags: linux, rpm, zypper

I just installed a totally wrongly packaged RPM on my openSUSE distribution (the packager added `/` and `/usr/*` as a file of the package, so I can't uninstall it without wiping the entire root FS)

How can I remove the package without touching any of the declared files?

Here are the infos :

```
rpm -qi nnn-4.0-1.x86_64
Name        : nnn
Version     : 4.0
Release     : 1
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Fri 28 May 2021 01:53:46 CEST
Group       : other
Size        : 112871
License     : BSD 2-Clause
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : nnn-4.0-1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Tue 13 Apr 2021 13:19:31 CEST
Build Host  : 43528e776956
Packager    : Arun Prakash Jana <engineerarun@gmail.com>
URL         : https://github.com/jarun/nnn
Summary     : The unorthodox terminal file manager.
Description :

Distribution: (none)
```

```
rpm -ql nnn-4.0-1.x86_64
/
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/nnn
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/nnn.1.gz
```

Comment: Maybe `rpm -e --justdb nnn`? Not sure, I haven't practiced rpm in a longtime.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thank you so much, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on a vague memory of `rpm`'s numerous options, and checking the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rpm.8.html), I think this should do the trick:

```
rpm -e --justdb nnn
rm /usr/bin/nnn /usr/share/man/man1/nnn.1.gz
```

Warning: untested, check your backups first.

Answer (score 0):

The rpm will not remove the directory when the directory is owned by some other package (and it is owned by `filesystem`) or when there are some other files not owned by any other package.

In other words: `rpm -q` of this package will not wipe your fs.

Comment: It actually did, and I was saved by BTRFS snapshots